# iOS Appium Camera Testing: How to inject video as if coming from camera to test apps using Appium

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests, appium, ios-camera

We want to automate the testing of an iOS app, the main functionality involves image processing from a video stream coming from the camera.

What is the best way to use Appium to inject a video stream and make it appear to the app as if it is coming from the camera of the device?

We are looking for a way to achieve this without changing the application code.

The question is about iOS, but if you know how to do it in Android that would be greatly appreciated, here is the question about Android:
[Android Appium Camera Testing: How to inject video as if coming from camera to test apps using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509442/android-appium-camera-testing-how-to-inject-video-as-if-coming-from-camera-to-t)