# Android Appium Camera Testing: How to inject video as if coming from camera to test apps using Appium

Tags: kotlin, automated-tests, appium, android-camera, android-camerax

We want to automate the testing of an app, the main functionality involves image processing from a video stream coming from the camera.

What is the best way to use Appium to inject a video stream and make it appear to the app as if it is coming from the camera of the device?

We are looking for a way to achieve this without changing the application code.

The question is about Android, but if you know how to do it in iOS that would be greatly appreciated, here is the question for iOS: iOS: [iOS Appium Camera Testing: How to inject video as if coming from camera to test apps using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469119/ios-appium-camera-testing-how-to-inject-video-as-if-coming-from-camera-to-test)

Comment: Only a few hours to grant the bounty!!!